# My Javascript gradient isn't working corectly

Tags: javascript

I am currently coding an interactive application using Javascript and the HTML canvas element. One of the things I'm coding is an opacity gradient. My gradient is supposed to fade from transparent to partially opaque, but the entire area I defined as the place to create the gradient is only partially opaque with no fade from transparency. Here's my code:

```
function draw() {

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 1000, 0, 0);

grd.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)");
grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 660, 1000, 10);

}
```

Comment: It appears to be a problem with my coordinates at var grd. I should be able to sort the problem out now.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to with the dimensions you use in `createLinearGradient` and `fillRect`. Right now you are defining your gradient area as a really tall thin rectangle [(0,0) to (0,1000)]. However, then you draw your gradient rectangle as a pretty big rectangle [(0,660) to (1000,10)].

I'm not exactly sure what your desired output looks like but it seems that your `ctx.fillRect` line is wrong. Trying the following works for me:

```
function draw() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 1000, 0, 0);

  grd.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 10, 1000, 660);

}
```

And the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vg6M/) if you are interested